# HTML TABLE TO JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I got a table in HTML with a button that submit the values as form post.

```
<form method=POST action="SendToServlet">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="num" value="0" size="5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num" value="0" size="5"></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="num1" value="0" size="5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num1" value="0" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input typw="SUBMIT">

</form>
```

I get the values of the table in servlet and I put them inside an array list that I send to jsp:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ArrayList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()){
        String parameterName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            String[] values= request.getParameterValues(parameterName);
            for(int i=0; i < values.length; i++){
                ArrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(values[i]));
                }
                request.setAttribute("valuesarray",ArrayList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

And I get them in JSP like this:

```
<%
    ArrayList<Integer> values= (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("valuesarray");
%>
    <table>
        <tr>
               <%for(int i = 0; i<values.size(); i++){%>
               <td><%=values.get(i) %></td>

             <%}%>
           </tr>
    </table>
```

But my result is like : 1 2 3 4. How can I show it the same like the HTML table?

My expected output:

```
1     |   2   |  Total row : 3
3     |   4   |  Total row : 7
-----------------------------
4 Col  6 Col
```

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: how are u displaying ur table initially?and how do u want it to display in the result?

Comment: why not you show as you doing it in case of input.

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone the table that I post to servlet is how I want to display in JSP the same table that I send.

Comment: You are not posting the table to servlet. You are posting the values of "input" tags under the "form" tag. Coincidentally the input tags happen to be in a table. Please clarify what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @Hirak, Well I want to send the values of the "input" tags to servlet calculate the sum of rows and columns dynamically and show the table with the sum of every row and every column.Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: are these tables in 2 different JSP pages?

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone Yest the form post is in a .html. Where I get values is servlet and where I show the table with results is JSP

Comment: @sankrish Updated with expected output

Comment: Where do you pass the row and column counts in your servlet ?

Comment: @sankrish well, I know how to do it, but not dynamically because If I increment in the html the table rows and columns, then in the jsp calculate all too.

Comment: use jquery to get the value from the table and calculate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table format remains like the one you showed (just change happens in number of tr tags each with two td tags in them):-

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="num" value="0" size="5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num" value="0" size="5"></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="num1" value="0" size="5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num1" value="0" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then Change your jsp code to this:-

```
 <%
        ArrayList<Integer> values= (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("valuesarray");
   %>
        <table>
    <%
    int k=0;
    int noOfRows=5;
    int noOftds=4;
    for(int i = 0; i<noOfRows; i++)

            {
        if(k==values.size()){break;}
        %>
                <tr>
                <%for(int j = 0; j<noOftds; j++){%>
                 <td><%=values.get(k) %></td>
                 <%k++%>
    <%          
    }%>
            </tr>
    <%          } %>
    </table>
```

Edit summary :- I have changed code so that you can specify the no of tr tags and no of td tags in each tr tag using the variables.

Comment: But the problem is, If now my table got 5 rows and 5 columns then that doesn't work.

Comment: I tryed your new code but dont work me correctly I dont understand why.

Comment: Sorry i missed something, try now